# How to loop through a group of divs one by one on each click in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to output the text of each span, one by one, within the respective group, every time I click its parent button.

I've tried different codes, but none of them worked for me.
So, this is what I've been working on.
http://jsfiddle.net/b6wfeaxz/2/

**js / jQuery**

```
$( ".button" ).on( "click", function(){
  $this = $(this);
  $this.find( '.letter' ).each(function() {

    $('.result').text($this.find('.letter').text());

  });
});
```

**HTML5**

```
<div class="result">A</div>

<div class="keypad">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="num">1</div>
    <span class="letter">A</span>
    <span class="letter">B</span>
    <span class="letter">C</span>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="num">2</div>
    <span class="letter">D</span>
    <span class="letter">E</span>
    <span class="letter">F</span>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="num">3</div>
    <span class="letter">G</span>
    <span class="letter">H</span>
    <span class="letter">I</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I expect this to go back and forth with every click within the same button. In other words, I need this to work the same as a telephone keypad function, but the actual output is all three letters at once.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/croup1yd/ -> I didn't change your code, it seems to work. What are you expecting to be different about it?

Comment: I need the output one by one and not all three letters at the same time. Let's say  that if I click on number "2", it should output the first letter (D) only, and if I click again the same number, then, the letter "D" should be replaced by the next letter (E), and If I click on the same number again, then it should replace the letter "E" with "F". But I would like that if I fourth time the number is clicked, then it should go back to the second letter (E) and then go to the 1st one again...

Comment: Do you mean you want a delay between each letter displaying? Eg if you click 'ABC' you want it to show A for one second, then B for one second, then C?

Comment: Oh I just realized what you mean. A 'telephone keypad'. You want the ABC button to output A when you click it once, B when you click it twice, C when you click it three times?

Comment: Yes! Just like that, but instead of coming back to the first letter when you went through all letters, I need the come back to the second letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fix, I realise this may not be the tidiest solution so feel free to edit:

```
var index     = 0;
var direction = 1;

$(".button").on("click", function () {

  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.hasClass("selected")) {
    if (index >= $this.find(".letter").length - 1) {
        direction *= -1;
    } else if (direction == -1 && index == 0) {
        direction *= -1;
    }
    index += direction;
  } else {
    $(".button").removeClass("selected");
    $this.addClass("selected");

    index = 0;
  }

  var result = $(this).children(".letter").eq(index).text();

  $(".result").text(result);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cndaeh7q/6/

Comment: That's close to what he wants, except he wants it to go back to B after pressing 4 times I think.

Comment: @TKol it does loop back around, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I would for it to go to the second letter instead of starting on the first letter.

Comment: I think he wants it to go 'ABCBABCBA'

Comment: Ah ok, give me a couple minutes. I'll be back with another edit soon.

Comment: Now, it kind of gets stuck on B and C. Just like @TKoL mentioned it, the pattern has to be "A-B-C-B-A"

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot @Halden Collier!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! @jQueryster

Comment: @Halden Collier, I posted another question and I thought you could help me out again since you're the original author of that code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761365/how-to-add-a-class-to-the-selected-span-in-jquery