# How to add a class to the selected span in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set a class (highlighted) to the span been selected and removing it when another span has been selected. Where do I need to set this class?

This is for a king of telephone keypad I'm working on. I'm basically working on a code that someone just answered on a previous question I posted. I've been trying to set this class, but I can't make it work as I wish.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/b6wfeaxz/3/

**JS / jQuery**

```
var index     = 0;
var direction = 1;

$(".button").on("click", function () {

  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.hasClass("selected")) {
    if (index >= $this.find(".letter").length - 1) {
        direction *= -1;
    } else if (direction == -1 && index == 0) {
        direction *= -1;
    }

        $(this).children(".letter").eq(index).addClass('highlighted');
    index += direction;
  } else {
    $(".button").removeClass("selected");
    $this.addClass("selected");

    index = 0;
  }

  var result = $(this).children(".letter").eq(index).text();

  $(".result").text(result);

});
```

**HTML**
    -

```
<div class="keypad">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="num">1</div>
    <span class="letter">A</span>
    <span class="letter">B</span>
    <span class="letter">C</span>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="num">2</div>
    <span class="letter">D</span>
    <span class="letter">E</span>
    <span class="letter">F</span>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="num">3</div>
    <span class="letter">G</span>
    <span class="letter">H</span>
    <span class="letter">I</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .highlighted {
   border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

I expect the span to be selected by adding the class **highlighted** and be removed when another letter has been selected.

Comment: so basically when you click on '1',  'A' should highlight. But if you press '1' again, 'A' should not be highlighted and 'B' should?

Comment: Yes, what ever letter the output is, that's what letter should be selected. Check the link I shared and see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a different approach, but seems easier to separate the highlight logic from the `selected` click event.

```js
var index     = 0;
var direction = 1;

$(".button").on("click", function () {
  
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.hasClass("selected")) {
   if (index >= $this.find(".letter").length - 1) {
     direction *= -1;
    } else if (direction == -1 && index == 0) {
     direction *= -1;
    }
   index += direction;
  } else {
    $(".button").removeClass("selected");
    $this.addClass("selected");
    
    index = 0;
  }
  
  removeHighlight();
  $(this).find('span.letters').addClass('highlighted');

  var result = $(this).find(".letter").eq(index).text();

  $(".result").text(result);
  
});

function removeHighlight() {
 var $letters = $('div.keypad').find('.letters');
  $letters.each(function() {
   $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
  });
}
```

```css
.button {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px 20px;
}
.num {
  font-size: 50px;
}
.result {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: blue;
  padding: 50px;
}
.highlighted {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
div.num {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result">A</div>

<div class="keypad">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="num">1</div>
    <span class="letters">
      <span class="letter">A</span>
      <span class="letter">B</span>
      <span class="letter">C</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="num">2</div>
    <span class="letters">
      <span class="letter">D</span>
      <span class="letter">E</span>
      <span class="letter">F</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="num">3</div>
    <span class="letters">
      <span class="letter">G</span>
      <span class="letter">H</span>
      <span class="letter">I</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're very close. It supposed to highlight the letters by clicking the number and not the letter it self.

Comment: Whatever letter is displaying in the output, that's the letter that it should be selected in the group of letters.

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it. What I did is that I specified exactly what span to be selected in this line `$(this).find('span.letters')` and added  `.eq(index)` so it would be `$(this).find('span.letters').eq(index)`. You basically did it! Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

From what I could understand the problem is removing the class from the unselected letters, right?
Try using the each function to remove the class from all letters first.

Like this:

```
$('.letter').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
})
$(this).children(".letter").eq(index).addClass('highlighted');
index += direction;
```

Comment: Well, for some reason, on the first click, doesn't capture the selection until the second click. In other words, skips the first click.

Comment: It skips the first click as that is just selecting which button you want to use.

Comment: Oh, OK. I get it... Is there a way to prevent that and keep the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick fix. Basically you keep an array of all the directions and indexes for each of the buttons. Then you select which one you need to edit by the index of the button clicked. This is not an ideal solution but it works. Hopefully that helped.

```
var index     = [0,0,0];
var direction = [1,1,1];

$(".button").on("click", function () {

  var $this = $(this);
    if (index[$this.index()] >= $this.find(".letter").length - 1) {
        direction[$this.index()] *= -1;
    } else if (direction[$this.index()] == -1 && index[$this.index()] == 0) {           
        direction[$this.index()] *= -1;
    }
    $('.letter').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
    })
    $(this).children(".letter").eq(index[$this.index()]).addClass('highlighted');

  var result = $(this).children(".letter").eq(index[$this.index()]).text();
  $(".result").text(result);
  //you have to add to the index after the result
  index[$this.index()] += direction[$this.index()];

});
```

Comment: your solution works for the selection part, but that confuses the output of the big letters. It skips the first letter on the output.

Comment: I have done the edit and it seems to be working now

Comment: It works, but what I noticed is that if I click on another number, it continues the pattern. And it shouldn't. It should reset the selection if a new number has been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have change your code a bit the changes are :

1. Add a counter to detect each click.
2. Add a num variable and actual_number in order to reset the counter between buttons.

   ```js
       var counter = 0;
       var num = "";
       $(".button").on("click", function (e) {
         var $this = $(this);
         actual_number  = $(this).children(".num").text();
         if(counter < 3 && num == actual_number ){
         $(".letter").removeClass('highlighted');
         $(this).children(".letter").eq(counter).addClass('highlighted');
          var result = $(this).children(".letter").eq(counter).text();
         $(".result").text(result);
         counter++;
         }else{
          counter=0;
          num =  $(this).children(".num").text();
          $(".letter").removeClass('highlighted');
         $(this).children(".letter").eq(counter).addClass('highlighted');
          var result = $(this).children(".letter").eq(counter).text();
         $(".result").text(result);
         counter++;
         }
         
       })
   ```

   ```css
       .button {
         float: left;
         width: 100px;
         height: 100px;
         margin: 20px 20px;
       }
       .num {
         font-size: 50px;
       }
       .result {
         font-size: 100px;
         color: blue;
         padding: 50px;
       }
       .highlighted {
         border: 1px solid red;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <div class="result">A</div>

       <div class="keypad">
         <div class="button">
           <div class="num">1</div>
           <span class="letter">A</span>
           <span class="letter">B</span>
           <span class="letter">C</span>
         </div>
         <div class="button">
           <div class="num">2</div>
           <span class="letter">D</span>
           <span class="letter">E</span>
           <span class="letter">F</span>
         </div>
         <div class="button">
           <div class="num">3</div>
           <span class="letter">G</span>
           <span class="letter">H</span>
           <span class="letter">I</span>
         </div>
       </div>
   ```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hello @stan chacon, it actually supposed to go between the middle letter if the same number is clicked. The pattern should be "A-B-C-B-A" when clicked on the same number. If a new number is clicked, then the it should start on the first letter of that number.